# Django Forcing BigAutoField even though Default is set to AutoField

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

so I upgraded from django 3.1 to 3.2 and on two of my models when I make migrations it keeps forcing me to change the auto id to `BigAutoField` even though I have (and had) `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'` in my settings file before I updated.

```
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='device',
            name='id',
            field=models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        )
```

What is strange is that it is only affecting a couple models, but the rest are fine and they all use `AutoField` as well.

I am not against using `BigAutoField` but the migration fails because of foreignkey constraints.

I have deleted the migrations in question and also scrubbed them from the applied migrations table in the database. How can I stop Django from forcing this migration? I am at a loss right now.

Here is my Device Model. As you can see I have not specifically set the primary key, which I have not done on any other model either and those are fine.

```
from django.db import models
from company.models import Company
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from main.models import uuid_pre_save_generator
from django.conf import settings
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
import json
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator, FileExtensionValidator


class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Image ID')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/",
                              validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'], 'Only .jpg files allowed')])

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Uploaded Image"
        verbose_name_plural = "Uploaded Images"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid


pre_save.connect(uuid_pre_save_generator, sender=UploadedImage)


def update_device_theme(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    related_devices = instance.devices.all()
    if related_devices:
        for d in related_devices:
            d.save()


def alert_device_update(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    device = Device.objects.get(uuid=instance.uuid)

    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = 'connect_{}'.format(instance.uuid)

    data = json.dumps({
        'message': {
            'type': 'device_update',
            'text': '',
            'data': {
                'device': device.connect,
            },
            'sender': {
                'type': 'server',
                'uuid': '',
                'first_name': '',
                'last_name': '',
                'company': '',
                'initial': '',
                'display_name': 'Server',
            },
        },
    })
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chatroom.message',
            'text': data
        }
    )


class DeviceDisplayTheme(models.Model):

    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Theme ID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Theme Name')
    show_header = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Show Header')
    show_footer = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Show Footer')
    header_bg_color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False,
                                       verbose_name='Header Background Color',
                                       default='rgba(255,255,255,.1)',
                                       validators=[
                                           RegexValidator(
                                               regex=r"^^rgba[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|"
                                                     r"\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|"
                                                     r"25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,){3}\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*[)]$",
                                               message='The header background color you have chosen is not formatted'
                                                       ' correctly',
                                           ),
                                       ])
    badge_bg_color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False,
                                      verbose_name='Device ID Badge Background Color',
                                      default='rgba(255,255,255,.2)',
                                      validators=[
                                           RegexValidator(
                                               regex=r"^^rgba[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|"
                                                     r"\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|"
                                                     r"25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,){3}\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*[)]$",
                                               message='The badge background color you have chosen is not formatted'
                                                       ' correctly',
                                           ),
                                      ])
    bg_color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False,
                                verbose_name='Background Color',
                                default='rgba(35,35,35,1)',
                                validators=[
                                    RegexValidator(
                                        regex=r"^^rgba[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|"
                                              r"\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|"
                                              r"25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,){3}\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*[)]$",
                                        message='The background color you have chosen is not formatted correctly',
                                    ),
                                ])
    font_color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False,
                                  verbose_name='Font Color',
                                  default='rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                                  validators=[
                                       RegexValidator(
                                           regex=r"^^rgba[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|"
                                                 r"\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|"
                                                 r"25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,){3}\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*[)]$",
                                           message='The font color you have chosen is not formatted correctly',
                                       ),
                                  ])
    idle_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                 verbose_name="Idle Text",
                                 default='Press Help Button In Case of Emergency')
    help_requested_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                           verbose_name="Help Requested Text",
                                           default='Emergency Help Requested')
    active_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                   verbose_name="Active Call Text",
                                   default='Emergency Call Accepted')
    response_prompt_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,
                                            verbose_name="Response Prompt Text",
                                            default='Press Yes/No Buttons to Respond')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='themes', verbose_name='Company',
                                blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    source_date_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    source_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Source ID')

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Device Display Theme"
        verbose_name_plural = "Device Display Themes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def settings(self):
        idle_text = '' if not self.idle_text else self.idle_text
        help_requested_text = '' if not self.help_requested_text else self.help_requested_text
        active_text = '' if not self.active_text else self.active_text
        response_prompt_text = '' if not self.response_prompt_text else self.response_prompt_text
        return {
            'pk': self.pk,
            'name': escape(self.name),
            'show_header': self.show_header,
            'show_footer': self.show_footer,
            'header_bg_color': self.header_bg_color,
            'bg_color': self.bg_color,
            'badge_bg_color': self.badge_bg_color,
            'font_color': self.font_color,
            'idle_text': escape(idle_text),
            'help_requested_text': escape(help_requested_text),
            'active_text': escape(active_text),
            'response_prompt_text': escape(response_prompt_text),
        }

    @property
    def settings_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.settings)


pre_save.connect(uuid_pre_save_generator, sender=DeviceDisplayTheme)
post_save.connect(update_device_theme, sender=DeviceDisplayTheme)


class Device(models.Model):
    UUID_CREATED = 0
    PROGRAMMED = 1
    ASSIGNED = 2

    lifecycle_stages = [
        (UUID_CREATED,  'Unique ID Created'),
        (PROGRAMMED, 'Memory Card Programmed'),
        (ASSIGNED, 'Owner Assigned'),
    ]

    statuses = [
        ('idle', 'Idle'),
        ('requested', 'Incoming Call Requested'),
        ('active', 'Live Call'),
    ]

    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Device ID')
    # Call Status [ Idle, Requested, Active ]
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=statuses, blank=False, default='idle', verbose_name="Call Status")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Active')
    self_monitored = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Self Monitored')

    # Display Theme
    theme = models.ForeignKey(DeviceDisplayTheme, related_name='devices', verbose_name='Display Theme',
                              blank=False, null=False, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    # Programming & Assignment
    initialized = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Initialized')
    lifecycle = models.IntegerField(choices=lifecycle_stages, default=0, verbose_name="Lifecycle Stage")
    software_version = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Software Version')
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Model Number')
    activation_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Activation Code')

    # Relationships
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='devices', verbose_name='Device Owner',
                              blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    callcenter = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='monitored_devices', verbose_name='Call Center',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    # Location & Address Details
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='Device Identifier')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Street Address", blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Apartment, Unit, Suite, or Floor", blank=True)
    address_locality = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="City/Town", blank=True)
    address_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="State", blank=True)
    address_postcode = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name="Zip Code", blank=True)
    address_country = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name="Country", blank=True)

    # Call-in Phone Number
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Call-in Phone Number",
                                    validators=[
                                        RegexValidator(
                                            regex=r"^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$",
                                            message='Phone number format is not valid, try (000) 000-0000',
                                        ),
                                    ])

    # Timestamps
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_last_online = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Device"
        verbose_name_plural = "Devices"
        ordering = ['uuid']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid

    def set_idle_state(self):
        self.state = 'idle'

    def set_requested_state(self):
        self.state = 'requested'

    def set_active_state(self):
        self.state = 'active'

    @property
    def full_address(self):
        def check_address_parts(value):
            if value == '' or value == ',':
                return False
            else:
                return True
        address_parts = [
            "%s," % self.address,
            "%s," % self.address2,
            "%s" % self.address_locality,
            "%s," % self.address_state,
            "%s" % self.address_postcode,
        ]
        return ' '.join(filter(check_address_parts, address_parts))

    @property
    def location_and_full_address(self):
        if self.location:
            if self.full_address:
                return '{} - {}'.format(self.full_address, self.location)
            return self.location
        return self.full_address

    @property
    def entry(self):
        address = '<div class="fs-6">{}</div>'.format(escape(self.full_address)) if self.full_address else ''
        location = '<div class="fs-6">{}</div>'.format(escape(self.location)) if self.location else ''
        return ' '.join((address, location))

    @property
    def connect(self):
        owner = '' if not self.owner else self.owner.connect
        callcenter = '' if not self.callcenter else self.callcenter.connect
        return {
            'type': 'device',
            'pk': self.pk,
            'uuid': self.uuid,
            'state': self.state,
            'first_name': '',
            'last_name': '',
            'owner': owner,
            'callcenter': callcenter,
            'initial': 'D',
            'display_name': 'Device {}'.format(self.uuid),
            'location': escape(self.location),
            'address': escape(self.full_address),
            'connect_version': settings.CONNECT_VERSION,
            'url_live_call': reverse('device_live_call', args=[self.uuid]),
            'theme': self.theme.settings,
        }

    @property
    def connect_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.connect)

    @property
    def connect_version(self):
        return settings.CONNECT_VERSION


pre_save.connect(uuid_pre_save_generator, sender=Device)
post_save.connect(alert_device_update, sender=Device)


class DeviceId(models.Model):
    STAGED = 0
    REQUESTED = 1
    CAPTURED = 2
    EXPIRED = 3

    device_uuid_status = [
        (STAGED, 'Staged'),
        (REQUESTED, 'Requested'),
        (CAPTURED, 'Captured'),
        (EXPIRED, 'Expired'),
    ]

    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Device ID')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=device_uuid_status, default=0, verbose_name="ID Status")

    programmer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='programmer', null=True,
                                   on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Programmer')

    # Timestamps
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_requested = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_captured = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_expired = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Device Id"
        verbose_name_plural = "Device Ids"
        ordering = ['date_created']


pre_save.connect(uuid_pre_save_generator, sender=DeviceId)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `Device` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added...btw, thanks for looking at this

Answer (score 6):

Well, I figured it out. For some reason the `BigAutoField` was set in the `apps.py` file in the app

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class DeviceConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'device'
```